# MySQL Cluster - strange syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, syntax

I have MySQL Cluster instance and want one column (BLOB) to be stored on disk instead of memory.
I tried to follow this tutorial: http://mikaelronstrom.blogspot.com/2006/02/how-to-define-table-that-uses-disk.html
And this is output I am getting:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE test1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> use test1;
Database changed
CREATE LOGFILE GROUP lg1
    -> ADD UNDOFILE 'undofile.dat'
    -> INITIAL_SIZE 16M
    -> UNDO_BUFFER_SIZE = 1M
    -> ENGINE = NDB;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '16M
UNDO_BUFFER_SIZE = 1M
ENGINE = NDB' at line 3
```

Here is syntax for this command: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-logfile-group.html
Any ideas why this is not working? I cannot find where I am violating this command syntax.

Comment: Why do you put `=` for some parameters and not others?

Comment: @Mat That is copied from tutorial I have provided. Even without any `=` error is still the same.

Comment: Is the error still there if you convert the `16M` to `16*1024*1024` (and the 1M respectively)?

Comment: Also test what happens if you put equal signs everywhere `CREATE LOGFILE GROUP lg1 ADD UNDOFILE 'undofile.dat' INITIAL_SIZE = 16M UNDO_BUFFER_SIZE = 1M ENGINE = NDB;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CREATE LOGFILE GROUP and CREATE TABLESPACE accept only bytes as unit.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62858

With MB converted to bytes logfile group was created successfully for me.